# Как правильно спарсить RSS, выводя только новые записи? php

Tags: php, парсер, rss

Всем привет. Есть RSS-лента сайта. Сайт обновляется каждые 5-10 минут. Хочу сделать парсер, который будет уведомлять о новых записях на мой email. Скажите, как правильно сделать, чтобы парсер брал только новые записи?

Каждый item в RSS содержит такую инфу:

```
<item>
<title>Заголовок</title>
<description>
    <![CDATA[...]]>
</description>
<pubDate>Sun, 06 Aug 2017 13:05:14 +0300</pubDate>
<link>
    https://site.com/item/asdasd
</link>
<category>
    <![CDATA[ Category ]]>
</category>
```

Можно ли это сделать по дате? Т.е. держать в БД дату последнего парсинга и выводить только те item'ы, которые больше этой даты?

Если да, то как `Sun, 06 Aug 2017 13:05:14 +0300` перевести в формат date?

Comment: вы об этом? `echo date('D, d M Y H:i:s O', strtotime('Sun, 06 Aug 2017 13:05:14'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

// Временная метка из <pubDate>
$pubDate = 'Sun, 06 Aug 2017 13:05:14 +0300';
$timestamp = strtotime($pubDate);

// Дата(и время) последней записи из БД
# (формат DATETIME: "0000-00-00 00:00:00")
$dbDate = '2017-08-06 13:05:00';
$datetime = strtotime($dbDate);

// Если дата последней новости больше последней записи в БД
if ($timestamp > $datetime) {
    // Выполнить обработку
}
```